# Как достать @username бота в телеграм?

Tags: python, kotlin, telegram-bot, telegram

Необходимо достать из бота его **@username** (**@name_bot**) по API. В документации ничего не нашел по этому поводу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[getMe](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getme)

Простой метод проверки токена аутентификации вашего бота. Не требует параметров. Возвращает основную информацию о боте в виде объекта [User](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user).

Поле username - Имя пользователя или бота

```
import telebot


bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token)

print(bot.get_me())
print(bot.get_me().username)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)

>>> {'id': 99**66, 'is_bot': True, 'first_name': 'example', 'username': 'example_bot', 'last_name': None, 'language_code': None, 'can_join_groups': True, 'can_read_all_group_messages': False, 'supports_inline_queries': False}

>>> example_bot
```